# how to replace kubernet master IP in single node cluster without using kubeadm

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, etcd

I want to change my master IP in single node k8s cluster without using kubeadm

I have setup the single node cluster using kubespray, now I want to change the main cluster ip

Comment: do you have only one master node?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vasily Angapov, Yes, I have only one master

Comment: @Vasily Angapov please let me know if there is any update